# Testing Retrofit2 network calls in Flow based architecture using MockWebServer

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

## TL;DR:

It appears that there is no other way to perform tests in a Flow based architecture using MockWebServer but to either force the test execution to `Dispatchers.Default` or use Thread.sleep() to await responses.

I've provided the running tests with all my experiments [here](https://github.com/cee-dee/flow-testing-issues). All tests are expected to pass, but most of them don't.

## Scenario

I decided to give MockWebServer a try for a couple of reasons:

- keep my tests as close to production: avoid using Mockito for Unit Tests, but instead use the real instances down to the network layer
- have real network access
- verify Json parsing
- verify response code handling

## What works flawlessly

In simple cases like fetching data from a Coroutine, everything worked out nicely:

- tests were fast
- tests were reliable and not flaky

## What causes trouble

When I moved on to Flow based architectures, things turned out to become complicated.

The Flow based scenario incorporates

- Flow / Coroutines
- FlowTurbine
- Retrofit 2
- MockWebServer

My Repository (SUT) looks like this:

```
class Repository @Inject constructor(
    private val dataService: DataService,
    dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) {

    private val selectorFlow: MutableStateFlow<String?> =
        MutableStateFlow(null)

    val data: Flow<Result<Data>> =
        selectorFlow
            .filterNotNull()
            .flatMapLatest { selector ->
                fetch(selector)
            }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .flowOn(dispatcher)

    suspend fun select(selector: String) {
        selectorFlow.emit(
            selector
        )
    }

    private suspend fun fetch(selector: String): Flow<Result<Data>> {
        return MutableStateFlow(
            runCatching {
                dataService.loadData(selector)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

So, my Repository shall provide data (which is fetched from network) based on a `selector`.

## I want to test a simple success case:

```
    @Test
    fun `test should pass but will not pass` {
        runTest {

            val sut = createRepository(
                mockWebServerUrl = mockWebServer.url
            )
            mockWebServer.enqueue(
                response = MockResponse()
                    .setResponseCode(200)
                    .setBody("{ \"value\": \"value1\", \"counter\": 0 }")
            )

            sut.select(selector)

            sut.data.test {
                val item = awaitItem()
                assertThat(item)
                    .isEqualTo(Result.success(Data(value = "value1")))
            }
        }
    }
```

Although, I've used `UnconfinedTestDispatchers` and FlowTurbine incorporates waiting, the test fails.

### Not passing modifications of the test:

I gave using

```
testScheduler.advanceUntilIdle()
val item = awaitItem()
```

a try, but that wasn't successul, either.

I managed to make the test work using

```
Thread.sleep(20)
val item = awaitItem()
```

### Passing modification of the test:

As I wasn't happy with that, I created a custom `Dispatcher` for OkHttp which immediately executes commands:

```
class InstantExecutorService : ExecutorService {
    override fun execute(command: Runnable) = command.run()
    ...
}

val dispatcher = Dispatcher(InstantExecutorService)
```

Using that, the above simple test succeeded and wasn't flaky anymore.

## Testing exception cases

So far, so good. Now, I wanted to create tests for failure scenarios like "no internet connection":

```
    @Test
    fun `test should pass but will not pass` { {
        mockWebServer.start()
        mockWebServer.shutdown()
        runTest {

            val sut = createRepository(mockWebServer.url)

            sut.select(selector)

            sut.data.test {
                val item = awaitItem()
                verifyFailingDueToConnectionIssue(item)
            }
        }
    }
```

The Result containing a `ConnectException` will never be received by this test.

### Not working modifications to the test:

I tried again using `advanceUntilIdle()` and using my custom OkHttp Dispatcher with immediate execution -- this time without any success.

### A partially working modification to the test:

Using

```
Thread.sleep(20)
val item = awaitItem()
```

I could make the test pass, but a Thread.sleep() is not what I want.

### Alternative investigations to rule out other causes:

In order to confirm that this problem is related to Retrofit, I exchanged the MockWebServer usage against a Mockito implementation when creating the repository:

```
fun createFailingStubBackedRepository(): Repository {
    val dataService = mock(DataService::class.java)
    runBlocking {
        doAnswer {
            Thread.sleep(50)
            throw RuntimeException()
        }
            .`when`(dataService).loadData(anyString())
    }
    return Repository(
        dataService = dataService,
        dispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
    )
}
```

Instantly, my tests succeeded.

## Workaround to avoid Thread.sleep()

When using `runTestDefaultDispatcher` instead of `runTest` the whole suite passes:

```
fun runTestDefaultDispatcher(
    testBody: suspend TestScope.() -> Unit
): TestResult {
    val defaultDispatcherTestBody : suspend TestScope.() -> Unit = {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            testBody()
        }
    }
    runTest(testBody = defaultDispatcherTestBody)
}
```

But that's imho contradicting the intentions of using the new `TestCoroutineScheduler`.

## Final words

As pointed out at the top of the post, you can check all of the tests in this [repository](https://github.com/cee-dee/flow-testing-issues)

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a quirk in the Retrofit implementation? Any help in fixing or/and debugging this strange behavior is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
ceedee